# HDD not detected by mainboard anymore, checked cables, checked hdd functionality - all work well, but the HDD is not detected

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I've exchanged my power supply and reconnected all of my SATA-drives. Now all drives are detected by the mainboard, but one - of course I checked all cables, and I use working cables and a working port on the mainboard 100%.
Also, I connected the "faulty" HDD with a SATA to USB Adapter, which showed me a perfectly normal working HDD.

I've never experienced this before, this is really a mistery to me...

I'll provide any additional information you might need.

My mainboard can't seem to find the HDD, although I use cables from a HDD, which gets found by the mainboard.

SOLUTION: i have a Western Digital Ultrastar He10/12 WDC WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0 with 8TB - this Disk was built out from an external HDD.

The Solution is either, to place non conductive foil on the third pin, counting from the Data-connector side -

(Sorry, i am not yet allowed to embed pictures...)

The other solution, the one i chose, is to not use the power cable directly connected to the mainboard, but with a Molex Power cable between Mainboard and the HDD.

So it looks like This: Power Supply -> Molex -> (through Adapter) SATA 15 pin power -> WD Drive

Then, everything should work like charm.

More Information regarding the problem:
quoting "accessrandom" on instructables.com:

The cause is a new SATA specification which includes the ability to disable power to the hard disk. When you look at the SATA power connection on the back of your hard drive, there are 15 pins that make contact with your power supply. It's the third pin that delivers a 3.3V signal that disables the drive. What we need to do is prevent that third pin from making contact with the power cable.

Comment: I assume you have tried a different SATA port?

Comment: Yes i have, different SATA Ports, different Cables... the HDD works via SATA/USB Adapter but not directly connected by a sata cable to the mainboard.

I currently try to update my UEFI Version, maybe this helps... i'm currently grasping any straw i can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution: I used a HDD from an External Drive - Pin 3 from the power  plug on the HDD must be deactivated - this works either by attaching non-conducting foil, or exchanging the Power cables with MOLEX Adapter.

See: https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Fix-the-33V-Pin-Issue-in-White-Label-Disks-/

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page change.